# Hiding and showing image using keydown function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I'm trying to hide an image and show another (essentially swapping them out) when the 'x' key is pressed using jQuery. Here is the piece of code I'm trying to fix (it does not currently work):

```
    .keydown(function(key){
  if (key.keyCode == '88') {
      $('.ryu-still').hide();
      $('.ryu-cool').show();
 }
});
```

And here's the full .js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ryu').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.ryu-still').hide();
        $('.ryu-ready').show();
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $('.ryu-still').show();
        $('.ryu-ready').hide();
    })
    .mousedown(function(){
        playHadouken();
        $('.ryu-ready').hide();
        $('.ryu-throwing').show();
        $('.hadouken').finish().show().animate(
            {'left': '1020px'},
            500,
            function(){
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).css('left', '520px');
            });
    })
    .mouseup(function(){
        $('.ryu-throwing').hide();
        $('.ryu-ready').show();
    })
    .keydown(function(key){
  if (key.keyCode == '88') {
      $('.ryu-still').hide();
      $('.ryu-cool').show();
 }
});

});

function playHadouken() {
    $('#hadouken-sound')[0].volume = 0.5;
    $('#hadouken-sound')[0].load();
    $('#hadouken-sound')[0].play();
}
```

You can find the full project here: https://github.com/elisuh/jquery-streetfighter

Comment: Try binding the `keydown` event to the document (instead of the `.ryu` class) - shows some HTML and we might be able to know if that works or not

Comment: What is or is not currently working?  What is the problem?

Comment: They keydown function is not working. When the x key is pressed, nothing happens.

Comment: does the rest of the code work? Also, they key code is a number (not a string)

Comment: Open the browser's Web Console and watch in the js panel if there are errors.

Comment: Linking to github is not helpful. You need to read the [ask] page to get some guidelines on how to improve your question - great questions prompt quick answers.  At the very least, add a [mcve]  - if the external link (with the necessary code) goes away (or it's not reachable) the question becomes incomplete and impossible to answer.  Help us, help you, please!

Comment: Apologies, thanks for the tip! I figured it out and will post my answer below. Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Wasn't aware of the number/string difference. Below is my solution. Thanks all.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(key) {
    if (key.keyCode === 88) {
      $('.ryu-still').hide();
      $('.ryu-ready').hide();
      $('.ryu-cool').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

They key code is a number (not a string)

See if this helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ryu-ready').hide();
  
  $(document).on('keydown', function(key) {
    
    
    if (key.keyCode === 88) {
      $('.ryu-still').toggle();
      $('.ryu-ready').toggle();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="ryu-still">Still</button>
<button class="ryu-ready">Ready</button>


<div classs="ryu">show or hide</div>
```